# SQL function returns wrong value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a function that takes 2 parameters: `@iEmployeeID` and `@dDate`.

It's purpose is to find a budget rate for the given parameters. In other words, it should find the largest date being smaller or equal to the `@dDate` argument, and return the rate that corresponds.

Budget rates are:

```
Start        Rate
-------      -----
01-01-2008   600
01-01-2009   800
01-01-2010   700
```

```
DECLARE @result decimal(38,20)

SELECT @result = decRate
FROM BudgetRates BR
WHERE BR.iRefEmployeeID = @iEmployeeID
GROUP BY decRate
HAVING MAX(BR.dStart) <= @dDate

RETURN @result
```

- When supplied the argument `06-06-2008`, it correctly returns 600.
- When supplied the argument `03-03-2009`, it correctly returns 800
- When supplied the argument `02-02-2010`, it should return 700. The function actually returns 800.

Where is the bug?

bug hunting:
If I tweak around with the figures, it seems to pick the largest rate if it has 2 values to pick from.

Comment: bughunting: Now if I "ruin" my data and edit the 700 rate to 810. It correctly picks the that rate when the question is 02-02-2010.

Comment: Ahh there was something.

Solution giving the correct answer:
    DECLARE @result decimal(38,20)
                
    SELECT TOP 1 @result = decRateWeekday
    FROM tbl_eCon_Target_BudgetRates BR
    WHERE BR.iRefEmployeeID = @iEmployeeID
    GROUP BY decRateWeekday, dStart
    HAVING MAX(BR.dStart) <= @dDate
    ORDER BY dStart DESC
        
    RETURN @result

thank you so much for the help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surely your code shouldn't be grouping at all?

```
SELECT TOP 1 @result = decRate
FROM BudgetRates BR
WHERE BR.iRefEmployeeID = @iEmployeeID
AND BR.dStart <= @dDate
ORDER BY BR.dStart DESC

RETURN @result
```

Comment: When I leave out the GROUP BY I get: Column 'BudgetRates.decRate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. And Top 1 picks the rate 600.

Comment: @DoStuffz - You can't have left out the GROUP BY if you get that message.

Comment: @DoStuffz: If `TOP 1` is picking a rate of 600, that sounds as if you left off the `DESC` on the `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 1):

You should select top 1 using `TOP 1` get the appropriate one with `ORDER BY`

```
DECLARE @result decimal(38,20)

SELECT TOP 1 @result = decRate
FROM BudgetRates BR
WHERE BR.iRefEmployeeID = @iEmployeeID
ORDER BY decRate DESC

RETURN @result
```

Comment: When I do this I get. "Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'SET ROW COUNT' within a function."

Comment: oh.. i forgot you can't do that in a function.. correcting for Top 1

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are supposed to use ranking functions here.

```
DECLARE @result decimal(38,20)

SELECT @result = decRate 
(
  SELECT decRate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY BR.dStart DESC) rownum
  FROM BudgetRates BR
  WHERE BR.iRefEmployeeID = @iEmployeeID
  AND BR.dStart <= @dDate
) sub
WHERE rownum = 1

RETURN @result
```

Answer (score 0):

try this mate:

```
select @result = decRate
    from BudgetRates
      inner join (
       select max(BR.dStart) as MaxDate
       from BudgetRates
      where BR.dStart <= @dDate
        and BR.iRefEmployeeID = @iEmployeeID
                 ) temp on tmep.MaxDate = BudgetRates.dStart
                   and BudgetRates.iRefEmployeeID = @iEmployeeID
```